# Moving Specific files to Specific folder using Python

Tags: python

I want to create and move files from  one folder to another in such a way that for ever 120 files a new folder will be getting created inside the newly created folder.

The files will be having specific naming structure: `X.0.JPEG`, `X.1.JEPG` to `X.1200.JPEG`

eg: `//path`
    Create `//path//New_folder`
    after this, folders will be created under this `"New_folder"` and 120 files will be moved to the new folder `"//path//New_folder//F1//(X.0 to X.119)"` the next to `"//path//New_folder//F2//(X.120 to X.239)"`...

This is my current code, the problem is its moving files randomly.

```
import os, os.path, shutil
folder = './path' 

images = [
            filename 
            for filename in os.listdir(folder) 
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folder, filename))
         ]  

global no
no = int(len(images)/120) + 1

img1 = images[0]

global folderName
folderName = img1.split('.')[0]

newDir = os.path.join(folder, folderName)
global folderCount
folderCount = 0

if not os.path.exists(newDir):

    os.makedirs(newDir)#folder created
    folderLimit = 120
    global imageCount
    imageCount = 0
    for image in images:
        if imageCount == folderLimit:
            imageCount = 0
        if imageCount == 0:
            folderCount = folderCount + 1
            newfoldername = os.path.join(newDir, folderName + '(' + str(folderCount) + ')' )
            os.makedirs(newfoldername)
        existingImageFolder = os.path.join(folder, image)
        new_image_path = os.path.join(newfoldername, image)
        shutil.move(existingImageFolder, new_image_path)
        imageCount = imageCount + 1
```

Comment: You have not formatted the code.

Comment: What do you mean by _randomly_?

Comment: I want X.0 to X.119 in the first folder itself, but here it moves files random like X.0 to X.12 and X.342 to X.500 like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this "randomness" is due to how `os.listdir(folder)` works - it returns file names in random order. [From documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir):

> `os.listdir(path)`
>
> Return a list containing the names of the entries in the directory given by path. **The list is in arbitrary order.** It does not include the special entries `'.'` and `'..'` even if they are present in the directory.

Therefore, what you need to do is to sort the result returned by `os.listdir`.

```
import os, os.path, shutil
folder = './path' 

lis_dir = [f for f in os.listdir(folder) if ('.' in f and f.split('.')[1].isnumeric())]
images = sorted(lis_dir, key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[1]))

folderLimit = 120
folderName = images[0].split('.')[0]
newDir = os.path.join(folder, folderName)
folderCount = 0

if not os.path.exists(newDir):
    os.makedirs(newDir)#folder created

for imageCount, image in enumerate(images):
    if (imageCount % folderLimit) == 0:
        folderCount += 1
        newfoldername = os.path.join(newDir, folderName + '(' + str(folderCount) + ')' )
        os.makedirs(newfoldername)
    existingImageFolder = os.path.join(folder, image)
    new_image_path = os.path.join(newfoldername, image)
    shutil.move(existingImageFolder, new_image_path)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but now i am getting error dir_content = sorted(os.listdir(folder), key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[1]))
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @Nandagopal.G Yeah, there was a bug. The reason is that `os.listdir` also returns all kind of other hidden files such as `.DS_Store`. Fixed in the last edit.

Comment: @Nandagopal.G You can also make filtering code more robust by implementing a more robust analysis of file names (i.e., how to deal with files without a `.` in their names).

Comment: Cool man, thanks a lot. Now i got a picture. I still get a new Bug:   lis_dir = [f for f in os.listdir(folder) if f.split('.')[1].isnumeric()]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @Nandagopal.G That is because you have files in your `path` directory that do not contain dots in their names. Either remove those files or enhance filtering algorithm to remove those files from the list returned by `os.listdir()`.

Comment: @Nandagopal.G You are welcome. See my latest edit - the code now should be more robust.